# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. httphandler session

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, session-variables

I am receiving "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." when I am trying to add access token from fb to the httpcurrent.session object.

I have the value in the var accessToken and when I am trying to put it in the session I am getting the error.

Please refer to the image:

[image]

Comment: Have you made sure Session is not null?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to enable session state in an HttpHandler, so you have to implement

```
System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState
```

Change to the following:

```
public class FacebookLogin : IHttpHandler, System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState
```